# How can I transfer my old ship inventory to a new ship inventory?

Tags: starfield

I would like to swap all the content of my first ship ("Frontier") to another one.

How can I transfer all the items in my old ship inventory to the new ship inventory?

Do I really have to transfer all the items manually to myself (and my companions), then run to the ship technician and ask for modifications. There I set the new ship with "Make Home Ship" to my new visible ship, return to my new active ship and unload all the items from my (and my companions) inventory back to the new ships inventory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your **cargo hold** is transferred automatically (and forcefully, whether you want them to or not) when you set a new *home* ship.

You may set a new home ship by speaking to any ship dealer and selecting the Modify Ship option. Select your non-home ship, and press Menu button (controller) or `H` (keyboard) to switch. All inventory is transferred to the new ship.

Stealing/pirating and registering a new ship will also switch your cargo hold over to the new ship.

ℹ Edit: There are a few minor exceptions to what is transferred. Most notably items *not* in the cargo hold. See comments below.

ℹ Note: If your new ship has less cargo capacity, it may overload it. Which is fine if it does— your ship will still fly and everything. You just won't be able to add more stuff to your overloaded ship until you clear its hold out some.

[image: set home ship]

Comment: This is basically correct but there (at least) two execeptions: 1) The content of the Captain's personal locker seems not to be transferred automatically. 2) Also whatever you leave on the floor on your old ship will not be transferred.

Comment: @PeterCo I would be very careful with leaving your items on the ground on your ship, no matter what you do. I learned the hard way that it does disappear and lost my 2000+ mass worth of resources. I don't know what exactly triggered it, but I was doing a series of "destroy the spacer ships" quest and something about getting into the space fights probably had something to do with it.

Comment: @JeffMercado argh! I know "loose" items (either things you've dropped or decoration) do get moved into your hold if you modify your ship in some way, overloading it if necessary :(

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: I believe the ship is wiped whenever you change home ships, either through direct action in the ships screen and "make home ship" or indirectly when you're transferred a ship by sitting in the captain's seat and taking off. Normal decorations that are "attached" to the ship are transferred to the hold, while everything else loose in it is discarded.

Comment: @JeffMercado - Some not attached items like pens, paper or plants visible on the tables seems to be transferred. Items on the ground of the old ship seems not be transferred. I'm not sure about books or medicine or items in the lockers of the crew (caps, toys, cigarettes, games).

Comment: @PeterCo Right, those items are "attached" as in they are part of those hubs prefurnished. When you buy that hub, you also get its flavor of junk if any. Armories will have a lot of empty cases, living quarters will have a lot of nicknacks, engineering will have some crafting benches, etc.